# How should I update the image cache in android when the image changes on a particular URL and URL remains same?

Tags: android, facebook, image, url, caching

For eg. Facebook keeps same URL for a user's profile pic and still able to identify when the pic is updated and clear its cache on the client side(android).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying that the URL of your image remains same whereas the image has changed. You dont have to do anything to load your images. The function you write to get the image from URL will automatically detect the image from URL and fetch it. for ex.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    load_img = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    load_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             new LoadImage().execute("https://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/node-cover-720x340.png");
        }
    });


}
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
        pDialog.show();

    }
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

         if(image != null){
         img.setImageBitmap(image);
         pDialog.dismiss();

         }else{

         pDialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     }
 }
```

else you can use a library called Picasso which can do all this in 1 line code.
ex.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("YOUR_URL").into(imageView);
```

where imageView is your imageview.

Comment: I have already loaded the image I want to remove it from the cache when server updates it.

Comment: which method are you using to load images?? Bitmap or any other ?? @sanjeev